# What have I done wrong in setting up Passenger/mod_rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I am attempting to get a Rails development environment up using a CentOS virtual machine. It will run Apache with Phusion Passenger, and I will access it from the host OS by entering the VM's LAN IP (eg `192.168.0.5`).

I have been able to run Rails apps perfectly using WEBrick, and I have been able to serve static pages and PHP perfectly from Apache. But getting Passenger set up is proving to be a baffling nightmare of endless problems for me, and I would absolutely love some help from someone who knows what they're doing here.

So here's what I've done.

1. Booted into a fresh CentOS 6.3 machine. Using yum, installed httpd (Apache 2.2), sqlite-devel, all the other good stuff you need.
2. Installed RVM (to `/home/vagrant/.rvm/`), and Ruby 2.1.2, which I can confirm is working perfectly.
3. Installed Passenger with `rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module`.
4. Added the following to my `httpd.conf`.

.

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule module_passenger.c>
    PassengerRoot /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45
    PassengerDefaultRuby /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby
</IfModule>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dangerzone/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/dangerzone/public>
            Allow from all
            Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally, in `/var/www/html`, I executed `rails new dangerzone` to create the app.

Initially, trying to access my app gave me a Passenger error 'no JS runtime', which thrilled me because I'd spent 5 or so hours trying to get Passenger recognised *at all*. I installed Node-JS through Yum, and my current error is a 500, `Internal server error`.

I see nothing in `/etc/httpd/logs/error_log`.

I've followed the instructions on the RVM and Passenger websites to a letter. I've Googled this problem until I'd read the entire top 30 results. I've wiped the VM and started from scratch in case I did something wrong -- same problem. So I'm kind of baffled. Have I screwed up something really obvious?

Comment: anything in `log/development.log` in the app?

Comment: @Baloo No, the log files in the app are blank.

Comment: All the log files in the app?  You've not got it running in production mode?  Also are you sure apache is set to log to `/etc/httpd/...` and not `/var/log/....`

Comment: @Baloo Oh, yes -- you're right. When I check the other location, I am seeing the error 'Missing secret_key_base for production environment'. I've Googled this problem now and the solutions all seem to focus around Git, which I'm not using...

Comment: Ok if it's that it's nothing to do with github.  It's [rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#config/secrets.yml)